# Delete content of file but keep name and hierarchy

Tags: bash, files, find, zsh

I have mirrored a directory structure but I don't care about the content of the files, I just want to keep the name and structure of everything.

How can I replace all files' (not folders) content with "nothing" (null, 1 byte, empty string or something like that)?

Comment: Are you on a Linux system?

Comment: @JeffSchaller OS X

Comment: @JeffSchaller I don't think this is kernel related. Tools: Gnu vs BSD vs UNIX, may be of relevance.

Comment: The tools are of relevance, If you like to save all meta data, you may like to have a look at my answer that explains how to do this with `star`.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I agree that the kernel isn't important; I asked for the OS as a shortcut/hint towards the available tools (I had `truncate` in mind, but led off with a POSIX option).

Comment: @JeffSchaller Linux has become a problem word. It is the name of a kernel, but is also used to describe some OSs that use the kernel, some that don't, but not some near identical OSs that do not use the kernel. e.g. WSL (Windows subsystem for linux) has no linux, Cygwin (gnu tools for Windows, not called liniux, has no linux, but in the context of your question, the answer is yes), same for debian BSD, or Gnu/Hurd. My point is we are making a land of confusion, by over loading the word Linux, to have two meanings.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Generically,

```
find /top -type f -exec cp /dev/null {} \;
```

or (courtesy of [jordanm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/13796/jordanm)):

```
find /top -type f -exec sh -c '> $1' -- {} \;
```

On a Linux system (or one with the [truncate command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/truncate) from the [GNU coreutils package](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/)):

```
find /top -type f -exec truncate -s 0 {} +
```

Comment: One more? `find /top -type f -exec sh -c '> $1' -- {} \;`

Comment: @JeffSchaller Thanks.  I guess all the data except date modified will remain same.  Could you confirm? (That date created, chmod attributes etc. wont change).

Comment: Faster and space-in-filename-safe variant: `find /top -type f -print0 | xargs -r0 truncate -s0`

Comment: @SimonRichter all 3 of the existing commands are safe to run with any filenames -- test it and see!

Comment: @Rahul, I don't have an OSX system to confirm, but the `cp` version should not change owner/permission; all of the commands would update the modification time. Creation date wouldn't have any reason to change, but I can't test that.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Thanks Jeff.  I checked, its as expected.  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 6):

With `zsh`:

```
for f (**/*(D.)) : > $f
```

`.` to do it only for regular files, `D` to include hidden files and files in hidden directories.

For a small number  of files, you can shorten it to `:>**/*(D.)`.

To keep the same size for the files, but make them sparse with no data (so taking no place on disk except on Apple's HFS+  file system which doesn't support sparse files):

```
find . -type f -exec perl -e '
  for (@ARGV) {
    unless (open F, "+<", $_) {warn "open $_: $!"; next}
    unless (seek F, 0, 2) {warn "seek $_: $!"; next}
    $size = tell F;
    unless (truncate F, 0) {warn "zap $_: $!"; next}
    unless (truncate F, $size) {warn "fill $_: $!"; next}
  }' {} +
```

Note that all those will  update the files' last modification time.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness here the bash version:

```
for f in **; do [ -f "$f" ] && [ ! -L "$f" ] && >"$f"; done
```

This needs the `globstar` option enabled (`shopt -s globstar`) and therefore at least bash version 4. (But if you where to use `zsh` you probably also wouldn't want to stick to its default Mac OS X version.)

Comment: You'd want to exclude symlinks as they could point outside the directory tree and fifos as that would hang. It  makes little sense to do it for other types of non-regular files, and could be dangerous for some types of device files (for instance it  would reboot the system for a /dev/watchdog). You also forgot to quote your variables which is OK for zsh but not for bash. Also note that it will skip hidden files.

Comment: IMHO, `[ -f "$f" ] && >"$f"` would be ever so slightly safer as it restricts the truncation to only act on regular files (not non-directories).

Comment: @Kusalananda, symlinks would still be a problem. You'd need: `[ -f "$f" ] && [ ! -L "$f" ] && > "$f"`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Ok, I applied your suggestion. (Sadly the `find` solution starts to look simpler now)

Answer (score 1):

If you like to keep all meta data for the files, I recommend to do the following:

- first archive the meta data of the files using:

  `star -c -dump -meta $STARTDIR > out.tar`
- then call `find` to remove the files.

Star allows you to `extract` the meta data from such a tar archive by calling:

```
star -xp -xmeta < out.tar
```

This creates a directory tree, that looks like the original tree, but all plain files then have size 0.

If you call:

```
star -xp -xmeta -force-hole < out.tar
```

the files are all sparse files with no content but with the right file size.

Note that the `star` method may also be of interest, when you have to report a problem to a software author and the problem only occurs with a specific file tree and you don't like to give away the content of the files.